# CSRFFilter implementaion in Play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am implementing CSRFFilter in PLay 2.2.1

```
import play.*;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;
public class Global extends GlobalSettings{

@Override
public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
Class[] filters = {CSRFFilter.class};
return filters;
}

}
```

I am getting **The import play.filters cannot be resolved**

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the Play filters helpers dependency to your project in `Build.scala`

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  filters
)
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and the filters helpers dependency was also added. Then I did a activator clean, and everything got well.